# Writing the data more than one times in the database as well as file

Tags: java, file

I am reading file from a shared map network drive directory. After reading file line by line to log into a folder and insert into database then delete.I am getting   some files are logging same data more than one times but other files are fine.Why it is logging more than one times?  Have any mistake in closing buffer  or file reading or parse method?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
            while (true) {        
                DirectoryFetcher fetch = new DirectoryFetcher();
                if (fetch.hasFile()) {              
                    for(File file:fetch.getFiles()){
                        try {                       
                            if(file.isFile()){                  

                                boolean flag = fetch.read(file);
                                 if(flag){
                                    file.delete();
                                 }                          

                              }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error(e.getMessage());
                            }                                   
                    }

                }
            }
        }

public class DirectoryFetcher {     

    public DirectoryFetcher() {
        ServerParams params = Configuration.getConfig().getServerParams();
        directory = new File(params.getLocalDirectory());
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            files = directory.listFiles();
        }else{

            logger.info("Map Network Drive is not Exist");
        }

    }

    boolean read(File file){
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = null;
            boolean flag = false;
             StringBuffer appendMessage = null;
             String completeMessage = null;
            try {
                if(file.exists()){
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                     appendMessage = new StringBuffer(16384); 
                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                
                         appendMessage.append(line);
                         appendMessage.append('\n');                 
                    }            
                     if(appendMessage != null){
                         completeMessage = appendMessage.toString();
                     }                       


                    if (completeMessage != null) {
                        if (!completeMessage.equals("")) {              

                            flag = new BioRad().parse(completeMessage,file);                        

                        }
                    }
                }   
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            finally{

                if(br != null){
                    try {

                        br.close();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }       


            return  flag ;
        }
}


public boolean parse(String message,File file) {        
        TestResultParser parser = null;     
        String[] records = message.split(RECORD_SPILIT_PATTERN);
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String record : records) {             
                result.add(record);
            }               
            logger.info("result:: "+result.size() );            
            parser = new TestResultParser(result);      
        return log(parser,file );
    }

    private boolean log(TestResultParser parser,File file) {
        boolean logFlag = false;        
        if(parser != null) {            
            TestResultMessage report = parser.getTestResultMessage();
            //TestResultModel   model = parser.getTestResultModel();
            List<Result> list = parser.getTestResultModelList();    
            logger.info("list:: "+ list.size());            
            logFlag  = (new DBLogger()).log(list);

//          for(Result model:list){             
//              if(model != null && model.getTestCode() != null && !model.getTestCode().equals("")) {
//                  (new DBLogger()).log(model);
//                  
//              }
//          }           

            if(report != null) {            
                if (params.isOutputOnFile()) {
                    (new FileLogger()).log(report,file.getName());
                }               
            }

        }       

        return logFlag;
    }
```

Comment: looks like there is another process concurrently writing to the network file. you need to lock the file during read

Comment: I am reading the file and parsing after that storing into DB. Most of the files are storing into DB without duplication .